# "Unknown custom element" warning inside a component tag, but not outside of it

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a component like this:

```
<template>
  <span class="my-icon">
    <img :src="iSrc" :alt="iname"/>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['iname'],
    computed: {
      iSrc() {
        return require('../../../assets/images/' + this.iname + '.png')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Using it inside a page like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Share it:</h3>
    <social-sharing inline-template network-tag="a">
      <div class="my-icons">
        <network network="facebook" class="fb-icon">
          <icon name="fb" />        
        </network> 
      </div>
    </social-sharing>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Icon from '~/comps/icon.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Icon
    }
  }
</script>
```

But it's throwing this error:

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

The `<social-sharing>` component is from a Vue plugin. If I use my `<icon>` component outside the `<social-sharing>` tag it works fine, but inside it throws the error.

Answer (score 12):

This is because you are using the `inline-template` special attribute on the `<social-sharing>` component.

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates):

> When the inline-template special attribute is present on a child component, the component will use its inner content as its template, rather than treating it as distributed content.

Everything inside the `<social-sharing>` tag is being treated as if it were the template definition for that component. And, since your `<icon>` component is being registered outside the `<social-sharing>` component's scope, it doesn't know what to do with the `<icon>` tag.

Since it looks like the `<social-sharing>` component is dependant on an `inline-template` definition, the only thing I can think to do is register the `<icon>` component globally:

```
// in your main.js file
import Icon from '~/comps/icon.vue'
Vue.component('Icon', Icon);
```

Then, since the `<icon>` component will be in the global scope, the `<social-sharing>` component will have a reference to it.

Answer (score -3):

I simply forgot to close a script tag in my component.

Comment: This should be a comment. While the "Unknown custom element" warning could be caused by an unclosed `<script>` tag, that's not the issue with this post.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I believe it should be an answer because it solved my problem after a long time of researching.